# Python Pandas datafram: How to count based on a column and then reset the count based on a matching criteria of two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a question about how to create a new count column based on column 2 changing from previous value but then the count resets based column 1 and column 2 matching on TRUE.

Below is an example of the data and the desired output.

The original data is:

```
| ColA | ColB |
| TRUE | TRUE |
| FALSE| FALSE|
| FALSE| FALSE| 
| FALSE| FALSE|  
| FALSE| FALSE| 
| FALSE| TRUE | 
| FALSE| FALSE| 
| FALSE| FALSE| 
| FALSE| FALSE| 
| FALSE| TRUE | 
| FALSE| FALSE|  
| FALSE| FALSE| 
| FALSE| FALSE|  
| FALSE| TRUE | 
| FALSE| FALSE| 
| FALSE| FALSE| 
| TRUE | TRUE |  
| FALSE| FALSE| 
| FALSE| FALSE|  
| FALSE| FALSE|
```

Desired output is:

```
| ColA | ColB | Count|
| TRUE | TRUE |   1  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   1  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   1  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   1  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   1  |
| FALSE| TRUE |   2  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   2  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   2  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   2  |
| FALSE| TRUE |   3  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   3  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   3  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   3  |
| FALSE| TRUE |   4  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   4  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   4  |
| TRUE | TRUE |   1  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   1  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   1  |
| FALSE| FALSE|   1  |
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried? Or any problems you are facing with the code?

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

group data by all True and take cumsum.

```
grp = df.all(axis=1).cumsum()
df.assign(count=df.any(axis=1).groupby(grp).cumsum())
```

out:

```
    ColA    ColB    count
0   True    True    1
1   False   False   1
2   False   False   1
3   False   False   1
4   False   False   1
5   False   True    2
6   False   False   2
7   False   False   2
8   False   False   2
9   False   True    3
10  False   False   3
11  False   False   3
12  False   False   3
13  False   True    4
14  False   False   4
15  False   False   4
16  True    True    1
17  False   False   1
18  False   False   1
19  False   False   1
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ColA': [True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False], 
        'ColB': [True,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False,True,False,False,False,True,False,False,True,False,False,False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly, you got to explain the logic more clearly. The new column adds up following the logic below.

- Starts with value "1"
- If next is TRUE + TRUE resets to 1
- If next is TRUE + FALSE adds 1 to previous value
- If next is FALSE + FALSE maintain current value

If you follow the logic above, you can write a code something like below,

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {'ColA': [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False],
        'ColB': [True, False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, True, False, False, False]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Initialize a counter and a list to store counts
count = 0
count_list = []

# Iterate through the rows of the DataFrame
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['ColA'] and row['ColB']:
        count = 1
    elif not row['ColA'] and row['ColB']:
        count += 1
    count_list.append(count)

# Add the count list as a new column
df['Count'] = count_list

print(df)
```

This gives you the answer,

```
 ColA   ColB  Count
0    True   True      1
1   False  False      1
2   False  False      1
3   False  False      1
4   False   True      2
5   False  False      2
6   False  False      2
7   False   True      3
8   False  False      3
9   False  False      3
10  False   True      4
11   True   True      1
12  False  False      1
13  False  False      1
14  False  False      1
```

Answer (score 0):

The combination of cumulative sums and aggregations will do the trick if `ColA` only is `TRUE` when `ColB` is, as in your example.

```
df["Count"] = (df["ColB"] == "TRUE").cumsum()
df["ColA_count"] = (df["ColA"] == "TRUE").cumsum()

df = df \
    .merge(
        df \
            .groupby("ColA_count") \
            .Count.min(),
        on="ColA_count",
        suffixes=[None, "_min"]
    )
df["Count"] = df["Count"] - df["Count_min"] + 1
df.drop(["ColA_count", "Count_min"], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     ColA   ColB  Count
0    TRUE   TRUE      1
1   FALSE  FALSE      1
2   FALSE  FALSE      1
3   FALSE  FALSE      1
4   FALSE  FALSE      1
5   FALSE   TRUE      2
6   FALSE  FALSE      2
7   FALSE  FALSE      2
8   FALSE  FALSE      2
9   FALSE   TRUE      3
10  FALSE  FALSE      3
11  FALSE  FALSE      3
12  FALSE  FALSE      3
13  FALSE   TRUE      4
14  FALSE  FALSE      4
15  FALSE  FALSE      4
16   TRUE   TRUE      1
17  FALSE  FALSE      1
18  FALSE  FALSE      1
19  FALSE  FALSE      1
```